# External CSS - Best method for different color for content area on 1/2 the site

Tags: css

I'm learning External CSS.

I have a CSS file that is working.  The pages use a background image and a content color.

I want to use a different content color as the background for photos--- about 1/2 of the pages in the site.  I want it to be in Ext CSS (not a page style), in case I want to change the color in the future.

What is the best practice when everything else in the CSS will be the same for all pages, except for the content color?

Please give a 'grade school' answer telling me exactly what I'll need to do.  I'm still learning terminology, so your clarity will really help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use SASS and variables.

Another solution (pure css) is to create a body class to determine your theme.

Example:

```
<body class="theme1"> or <body class="theme2">
```

And set your css:

```
.theme1 .my-div
.theme2 .my-div
```

With your theme colors

Comment: I'm sorry--- I said I'm a beginner... What is SASS?  I've never used themes.  To clarify, this is a regular website, not a Wordpress site.  Could you clarify please?

Comment: Sass is a CSS pre-processor. It extends css features and allow to use variables, mixins and more. As i said, this is a pre-processor and your final result is a CSS file. You can read more here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in this way:

```
.color1{
      color: #000000;}
.color2{
      color: #ffffff;}
```

You can name color1 and color2 as anything you want and save these styles in your css file. Use these classes where you want like:

```
<button class="color1">Good Button</button>
```

You can change color values and will reflect everywhere.

Comment: I do not want color on text.  I want to change the entire content AREA to have a separate color than what other pages use.  Will your suggestion do what I need?

Comment: Just use the respective color class in div tag of your content like <div class="color1">your content </div>